# Not Able to Access Attribute of a Constructor in a method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, .net-core

I am learning DotNet Core.
This is my Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Practinig_Student.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Practinig_Student.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly EmployeeContext _dbcontext;
        public EmployeeController(EmployeeContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbcontext = dbContext;
        }
        public IActionResult Employee_Details(int id)
        {
            // EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();

            //Employee employee = dbContext.Employees.Single(emp => emp.Id == id);
            
            var emplst = dbContext.Employees.Single(emp => emp.Id == id);
            
            
            return View(emplst);
        }
    }
}
```

I Am getting an error in line
`var emplst = dbContext.Employees.Single(emp => emp.Id == id);`

where I am not able access `dbContext`
The Error I am getting is *the Name dbContext does not Exist in the current context*

i tried a lot of solutions but error does not go. also i don't understand why the error is coming. help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `_dbContext`, not `dbContext`

Comment: Thank You. i was following a tutorial from (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/entity-framework-database-first-in-asp-net-core2/) in which he used dbContext thats why i using it.